# Rails Friendly ID: slug is not generated on model.new or model.import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slug, friendly-id, activerecord-import

Hi I am using friendly_id gem,

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

Here Student.create generates a slug as name as required.

But in my case, I am creating array of Student using 'new' method and saving to database using active-record-import

```
student_names.uniq.each do |s|
  students << Student.new(name: s)
end

Student.import students, on_duplicate_key_update: {
    conflict_target: [:name],
    timestamps: true
}
```

On 'new', it doesn't create slug and also on import.

How can I generate slug on import? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FriendlyId uses a `before_validation` callback to generate and set the slug
([doc](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Gotchas__Common_Problems)), but `activerecord-import` does NOT call ActiveRecord callbacks ...([wiki](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Callbacks)).

So, you need to call `before_validation` callbacks manually:

```ruby
students.each do |student|
  # Note: if you do not pass the `{ false }` block, `after_callback` will be called and slug will be cleared.
  student.run_callbacks(:validation) { false }
end
Student.import ...
```